# Show that a one dimensional $\mathfrak {g}\!-\!\operatorname{module}$ is irreducible

Tags: modules, lie-algebras

I want to show that a one dimensional $\mathfrak {g}\!-\!\operatorname{module}$ is irreducible.

My problem comes down to undestanding the basis of this object. Now assuming the basis works in the same way that the basis of a vectorspace works, I imagine the following argument works:

Let $U$ be a submodule of $V$, where $V$ is our $\mathfrak g\! - \! \operatorname{module}$, and let $V$ have the basis $\{v\}$. Then the submodule $U$ has basis $\{v\}$ or $\{0\}$, hence $U=V$ or $U$ is the zero ideal, and hence $V$ is irreducible.

But perhaps the basis works in a different way. I think my confusion stems from how frequently we alternate between talking about modules and representations.

Comment: A nonzero submodule has either dimension $1$ or $0$. In any case, it is either the trivial submodule or the whole module, which is what you want. Note the fact a one dimensional representation (of whatever structure you're dealing with) is irreducible is more or less independent of what structure you're considering. The important fact is that subrepresentations are also subspaces, are you can control subspaces by their dimension.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thank you, I think the subspace part solves my mental confusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be confusing talking about modules one moment and then talking about representations the next. In your case there isn't much difference. In fact, the confusion shouldn't confuse you.

A Lie algebra module is a vector space such that ...

A Lie algebra module is irreducible is there are no invariant (non trivial) proper submodules.

Since the dimension is one, there are no (non-trivial) proper submodules. So there isn't really anything to prove.

Comment: I guess I had an implicit question: Am I safe to talk about the basis of a g-module in the same way I would talk about a vector space basis? I.e for a two dimensional g-module, is it safe to say I have the basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ or is there something else going on? I can't see any alternative, but also I know that sometimes there are unknown, unknowns.

Comment: @LieAlgebra: Yes, a Lie algebra module is a vector space. And this vector space has a basis.

Comment: @LieAlgebra A big part of representation theory is phrasing things in terms of vector spaces so that one can use the powerful tools of linear algebra.